# Foundation 5 not compatible with Magic Zoom Plus

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, magiczoomplus

I have an example link here: http://www.kubikdesign.com.au/demo/magiczoomplus/

Basically when you click on the "zoom to expand" the page jumps to the top before opening the modal.

The problem is that foundation requires body and html to have a height of 100% for off-canvas to work (see foundations _global.scss).

If I use the following it fixes the jumping bug and off canvas seems to still work fine.

```
body {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

My question is, is this the best approach? Is my solution sound?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best option is to use the recent Magic Zoom Plus v5.1.11 which addresses this issue.

You can download the latest version from here:

https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/